# How to remove A record in DNS zone in WHM/cPanel using their API with PHP

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

I am trying to remove an A record in a domain's zone using the WHM API or cPanel API with PHP. I came across this [API call](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+ZoneEdit%3A%3Aremove_zone_record) but it needs a line number for that record, How do I get this line number without having to go and check the zone manually, but using PHP.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the [ZoneEdit::fetchzone_records](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+ZoneEdit%3A%3Afetchzone_records) API2 call to get the zone file via the API.  Then you can use PHP to match the line you're interested in and use the [ZoneEdit::remove_zone_record](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+ZoneEdit%3A%3Aremove_zone_record) to remove that line.

It's a little bit more work than a single API call, but it does offer you the flexablity of chosing the match criteria for the record.